# Maximum number of augmenting paths in symmetric difference of maximum and another matching

Tags: graph-theory

This [tutorial](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/%7Eleon/tcs/lecture2.pdf) (page 22) on Hopcroft-Karp algorithm for maximum bipartite matching states the following:

> Let $M^*$ be a maximum matching, and let $M$ be any matching in $G = (V, E)$. ...
>
> Let us consider the graph $G'=(V, M \oplus M^*)$. It contains at most $|M^*|-|M|$ augmenting paths with respect to $M$.

Here $M\oplus M^*$ is the symmetric difference between $M$ and $M^*$. But how does the last line (*It contains at most $|M^*|-|M|$ augmenting paths with respect to $M$*) follow?

Comment: Each augmenting path increases the size of the matching by $1$.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon But how does it prove the statement? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The size of the matching $M$ is $|M|$.  So you're starting with size $|M|$--then, each augmenting path can increase the size of the matching by $1$, so after $|M^*| - |M|$ augmenting paths there are $|M| + |M^*| - |M| = |M^*|$ augmenting paths.  There can't be more, because $M^*$ is a maximum matching.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Post intended to take this question off the "unanswered" list*

---

Each augmenting path increases the size of the matching by $1$.

The size of the matching $M$ is $|M|$. So you're starting with size $|M|$: then, each augmenting path can increase the size of the matching by $1$, so after $|M^∗|−|M|$ augmenting paths there are $|M|+|M^∗|−|M|=|M^∗|$ augmenting paths. There can't be more, because $M^∗$ is a maximum matching.